# How to deserialize a field that's either a string or an array of elements?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have some xml documents that contain a section that EITHER looks like this:

```xml
<MY_FIELD>
    <P>Some text I want here</P>
</MY_FIELD>
```

OR, it looks like this:

```xml
<MY_FIELD>Some text I want here</MY_FIELD>
```

For the latter, which is about 90% of the occurrences, this works:

```cs
[XmlElement("MY_FIELD")]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

For the former, this seems to work:

```cs
[XmlArray("MY_FIELD")]
[XmlArrayItem("P")]
public string[] MyFieldPs { get; set; }
```

However, I can't figure out how to write something that gets me both. If I try to reference `MY_FIELD` twice (and thus have both `MyField` and `MyFieldPs` in my class), then I get the error

```
The XML element 'MY_FIELD' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope.
```

Is there a way for both to work at the same time?

Comment: For now I've solved this by "manually" handling the XML documents that I know differ in this way using system.xml.linq.xelement.